# Proper graphics for iOS Device Family

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6

As the iOS device family gets bigger with the arrival of the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ I'm a bit confused as to what graphics you need to provide in order to fully optimize the visual experience for all devices..

This is what I know:

- iPhone (Non-Retina): image.png (50px x 50px)
- iPhone 4/4s/5/5s/5c (Retina): image@2x.png (100px x 100px)
- iPhone 6: ?????????
- iPhone 6+ (HD Retina): image@3x.png

So I understand that if you provide a graphic in the regular (image.png) format, the @2x format (image@2x.png), and the @3x (image@3x.png) format, that you should be good to go, but how about the iPhone 6? The graphics and layout that I have used for iPhone 5 devices just scales to fit the bigger screen of the iPhone 6, but I am wondering whether I need a different set of graphics for iPhone 6 as well?

Basically, I am somewhat confused as to how we are supposed to export each graphical asset in our projects so that it will work seamlessly for all the devices, including the new guys!

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this matter. It's probably a simple solution, but some nice clarification on the matter would be awesome!

Thanks.

Comment: If your app is scaling then you didn't add the iPhone 6/6+ launch images. If you just want the scaling then don't do anything special at all for the iPhone 6/6+. BTW - iPhone 6 uses `@2x`.

Comment: The asset catalog gives you placeholders with the expected dimensions.

Comment: I don't want scaling - does that mean that I need to provide a different set of graphics at a different size for the iPhone 6? @rmaddy

Comment: The iPhone 6 (and 6+) need their own launch images if you don't want scaling. Other than that you don't need anything special for either. Providing `@3x` images for the iPhone 6+ is optional (for now at least).

Comment: @rmaddy So if I do provide the iPhone 6 (and 6+) their own launch images, doesn't that mean that without scaling there will be a bunch of unused blackspace around the edges of the screen?

Comment: Why would there be? You are using storyboards with auto layout, right? Or are you talking about other full screen-size images in your app? If so, you of course need to provide properly sized images as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy then how do we reference these images is my question? If an image that has the '@2x' suffix is for both iPhone 4/5/6 (excluding 6+) then how does the program know to use the different size images? Do I have to hardcode it in to load a specific image depending on the currentDevice?

Comment: For things like icons you don't do anything special. If your images are screen sized then you need to provide your own logic to load the right sized image.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the help. I think everything has been clarified now!